# Image editing on iphone

Tags: iphone, image, scale, edit, crop

In my app i need to select a image from photos library and then user should be able to crop or scale the the image. Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) should do the trick.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [UIImagePickerController new];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
[yourViewController presentModalViewController:picker];
```

Then we need to implement the delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}
```

Comment: By setting picker.allowsEditing, the controller will automatically let the user crop and scale it before returning it to you.

Comment: How can I change 'Choose' button name in the picker modal view in to 'Done'?

Comment: Apple says you're not allowed to modify the modal controller at all, so I don't think it's possible if you want to get into the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UIImagePickerController` to let the user select an image from the photos library.

Answer (score 0):

@denizen
The
`[yourViewController presentModalViewController:picker];` needs an animated:BOOL.

Like: `[yourViewController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at [SSPhotoCropperViewController](http://www.ardalahmet.com/2011/10/17/ssphotocropperviewcontroller-a-custom-viewcontroller-that-provides-ui-for-cropping-photos-in-ios-apps/). It’s a custom view controller that provides a simple, configurable and easy-to-use UI for cropping and scaling photos in iPhone & iPod Touch apps.

For picking photos from the Photo Library, UIImagePickerController does well. However you cannot use it for the photos you get from another sources, say Flickr, FB etc.

Here is the [tutorial](http://www.ardalahmet.com/2011/10/17/ssphotocropperviewcontroller-a-custom-viewcontroller-that-provides-ui-for-cropping-photos-in-ios-apps/) and the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController) for SSPhotoCropperViewController.